# Extrair parte do texto de célula de email

Tags: microsoft-excel, algoritmo-de-busca

Como consigo extrair parte do email depois do último "."?

Na primeira linha obtenho o que quero.
Na segunda linha o problema é que está a extrair depois do primeiro ponto e não do último.

Com o seguinte código:

```
=DIREITA(C3;NÚM.CARAT(C3)-PROCURAR(".";C3))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a fórmula **PROCURAR** retorna a primeira ocorrência do carácter, enquanto o que você precisa é do índice da última ocorrência.

Para obter o comportamento de busca da direita para esquerda é necessário implementar você mesmo essa função.

Para criar a função:

1. Pressione Alt+F11 na planilha de Excel. A janela do VBA será aberta.
2. Clique sobre o nome do projeto VBAProject à esquerda
3. Escolha Inserir > Módulo.
4. Cole o código abaixo, na janela de Edição do Código que irá abrir.

```vb
Public Function PROCURAR_DIREITA(ByVal text As String, ByRef cell As Range) As String

PROCURAR_DIREITA = InStrRev(cell.text, text)

End Function
```

5. Volte na sua planilha e substitua a fórmula onde é:

```
=DIREITA(C3;NÚM.CARACT(C3)-PROCURAR(".";C3))
```

por:

```
=DIREITA(C3;NÚM.CARACT(C3)-PROCURAR_DIREITA(".";C3))
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!